# Workstation crashed - how to fix SVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, windows-xp

We use SVN with Visual Studio 2008 for SSIS development on Windows XP.

One of the workstations belonging to my teammate crashed.  Fortunately, it was just a windows crash so he was able to save the SVN-linked code folder from his machine.

Now that his workstation is rebuilt, he got everything back from SVN.

How do we figure out all the code files that had changed on his machine before the crash and put it back into SVN?

Answer (score 3):

Brute force approach would be just to checkout folder from SVN and then copy old files over, excluding '.svn' folders. Then run 'svn status' to see what files are marked as added/modified/removed. Inspect the differences and commit the changes.

Perhaps there are better approach but above should work.